# INSERT with SELECT works once

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables on my SQLite db as follow:

TABLE first_names

```
id
name
gender
```

TABLE last_names

```
id
name
```

TABLE names

```
id
first
last
gender
birthday (null)
used (default 0)
```

Where first and last are unique and also have a index with both being unique on the names table.

In order to fed names table I have used the below query, which worked the first time but after I had added a new name to the last_names and tried to use it again it failed.

```
INSERT INTO names (first, last, gender) 
       SELECT f.name AS first, l.name AS last, f.gender AS gender 
              FROM first_names f 
              LEFT JOIN last_names l 
              WHERE f.name NOT IN (SELECT first FROM names) AND 
                    l.name NOT IN (SELECT last FROM names)
```

Have also tried using `(first, last, gender, [birthday], [used])` with values as `null AS [birthday], 0 AS [used]` but since it birthday is set to null on the table design and used to 0 as default and it worked on the first time didnt think it would be needed nor it made any difference anyway.

I would think it is because of the unique fields however I do have a WHERE to make sure the names are not already in the table names.

I have tried the query using C# and SQLiteAdmin both executing without requesting result or else it doesnt work.

What is wrong with my query and why it only works once ?

Comment: What do you mean the query failed?  Did it not insert any records? Did it throw an error? What was the error?

Comment: @AdamWenger it doesnt throw any errors it just fails silently... And yes it doesnt add any new records where it was supose to add new names using the new last name I had just added. In fact in the SQLiteAdmin it says query executed and the amount of ms.

Comment: I'm all for "normalization", but I think three tables for one name is a bit excessive :)  IMHO...

Comment: @AdamWenger none, should I change it to UNION instead ?

Comment: @paulsm4 well thats not the issue here but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:
`WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM names n WHERE n.first=f.name AND n.last=l.name)`

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking that the first and last names are on the same record
I haven't run this through a sql command line, but it should work:

```
INSERT INTO names (first, last, gender) 
       SELECT f.name AS first, l.name AS last, f.gender AS gender 
              FROM first_names f 
              LEFT JOIN last_names l 
              WHERE f.name NOT IN (SELECT subquery.first FROM (SELECT * FROM names WHERE l.name = last AND f.gender=gender) subquery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query only works once because even if you have added another name to last_names, there is no value in first_names.name which is not present in names.first:

```
WHERE 
  f.name NOT IN (SELECT first FROM names) AND
  l.name NOT IN (SELECT last FROM names)
```

All the posible values for f.name are included in `SELECT first FROM names`

Perhaps you want to join these clauses with an OR, rather than an AND.